# Debugging Goodreads Bookshelf Request

Tags: ios, swift, xml, asynchronous, oauth

Currently building a Swift iOS app using the api and I’m coming up against something funky. I’m trying to cycle through an array of shelves and pull down data for each shelf using a for loop with Goodreads’ [reviews.list API method](https://www.goodreads.com/api/index#reviews.list).

Here’s what it looks like:

```
func getBooksFromShelf(_ oauthswift: OAuth1Swift, userID: String, shelf: Shelf, name: String) {
        let _ = oauthswift.client.get(
            "https://www.goodreads.com/review/list?v=2",
            parameters: ["key": developerKey, "id": userID, "shelf": name, "sort": "date_added"],
            success: { response in
                let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data)
                for review in xml["GoodreadsResponse"]["reviews"]["review"].all {
                    let book = review["book"]
                    let bookID = book["id"].element!.text
                    let bookTitle = book["title"].element!.text
                    let bookCoverURL = URL(string: book["image_url"].element!.text)

                    var bookAuthors = "by "
                    for author in book["authors"].all {
                        bookAuthors += author["author"]["name"].element!.text
                    }

                    let newBook = Book.init(id: bookID, title: bookTitle, authors: bookAuthors, cover: bookCoverURL)
                    shelf.books.append(newBook)
                }
        },
```

The problem is each run through the loop returns the data for https://www.goodreads.com/review/list/USER_ID_HERE.xml?key=DEVELOPER_KEY_HERE&v=2  as if no parameters were added to the request at all. But when I replace the *name* variable with the string of a shelf I know exists —like *"currently-reading"*—I get the proper result https://www.goodreads.com/review/list/USER_ID_HERE.xml?key=DEVELOPER_KEY_HERE&v=2&shelf=currently-reading.

I’ve tried dropping the parameters array and creating the URL string myself but that’s not working either. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35833063/debugging-an-api-request) but it’s not quite the same since I’m not getting an error message, just the wrong url. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured out the problem: I was setting capitalization on the Shelf names, which was messing up the end URL query, which is case-sensitive. Solved it creating two separate variables when the shelf object is created, one for the string the API returns—"want-to-read"— and one for the user friendly string that gets shown in the app which is "Want to Read".